# How to write a value of a column in the title of a graphic?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df

```
        CODE  DATE          TMAX    TMIN      NOMBRE
0       130 1/01/1991       32.6    23.4      RICA PLAYA
.
10866   132 1/01/1991       35.2    0         PUERTO PIZARRO
.
21824   134 1/01/1991                         PAPAYAL
.
32690   135 1/01/1991       30  23            EL SALTO
.
42704   136 1/01/1991                         CAÑAVERAL
.
```

I'm making many time series graphic of TMAX and TMIN for every unique `df['CODE']` value. When i write the title i put:

```
df.plot('DATE',['TMAX','TMIN'],title='ESTACION' + str(df.loc[df['CODE'] == i,'NOMBRE'])
```

But when i use `str(df.loc[df['CODE'] == i,'NAME']` to get the value i'm getting also the index, dtype and the name of the header like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get only the value in the title?

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc[df['CODE'] == i,'NOMBRE']` still returns you a series, hence you see `dtype` and so. Try `df.loc[df['CODE'] == i,'NOMBRE'].iloc[0]`.

Also, instead of trying to loop through `df.CODE.unique()`, consider looping with `groupby`:

```
for code, data in df.groupby('CODE'):
    nombre = data['NOMBRE'].iloc[0]

    data.plot('DATE',['TMAX','TMIN'],title=f'ESTACION {nombre}')
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang. Your code improved mine. And do you know how to insert this? I have 3 axes and i want to put the axes every two years with this code. This code is below the for statement:       fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=False,figsize=(11, 9))
    #ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(2))

Comment: @Javier Sorry, without the sample data, what you already tried and what you expect, I can't really help. Also it looks like a separate problem from this one?